# Including non-TypeScript JS files in TypeScript-generated Require define

Tags: requirejs, typescript

Let's say I have the following TypeScript file:

```
import module1 = require( 'module1' );
import module2 = require( 'module2' );

...some code...
```

This would generate the following JavaScript on compilation:

```
define( [ 'require', 'exports', 'module1', 'module2' ], function ( require, exports, module1, module2 ) {
...
}
```

However, what if I want to include a file that's NOT a TypeScript module? I want it to be loaded by RequireJS, as it has dependencies that are also loaded by RequireJS. If I try to add e.g. this:

```
import someJsFile = require ( 'someJsFile' );
```

I just get a "Module cannot be aliased to a non-module type" error on compilation. If I skip the `import` part and just do `require( 'someJsFile' )`, it compiles, but the JavaScript it generates is a non-functional nested define instead:

```
define( [ 'require', 'exports', 'module1', 'module2' ], function ( require, exports, module1, module2 ) {
    define( [ 'someJsFile' ], function ( someJsFile ) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way of including JavaScript files in the outer, "correct" RequireJS define without having to convert the JS files to TS modules myself? Or do I have to manually create a RequireJS define and drop the `import x = require( 'x' )` statements altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `amd-dependency`. In your case :

```
/// <amd-dependency path="someJsFile" />
declare var someVarFromJsFile: any;
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I had tried that before, but I always put it _after_ the `import` statements, which didn't have any effect, so I assumed that approach was fruitless. Tried putting it at the top of the file now - works like a charm. Thanks!